# Gensim word2vec in python3 missing vocab

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm using gensim implementation of Word2Vec. I have the following code snippet:

```
print('training model')
model = Word2Vec(Sentences(start, end))
print('trained model:', model)
print('vocab:', model.vocab.keys())
```

When I run this in python2, it runs as expected. The final print is all the words in the vocabulary.

However, if I run it in python3, I get an error:

```
trained model: Word2Vec(vocab=102, size=100, alpha=0.025)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learn.py", line 58, in <module>
    train(to_datetime('-4h'), to_datetime('now'), 'model.out')
  File "learn.py", line 23, in train
    print('vocab:', model.vocab.keys())
AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'vocab'
```

What is going on? Is gensim word2vec not compatible with python3?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Are you using the same version of gensim in both places? Gensim 1.0.0 moves `vocab` to a helper object, so whereas in pre-1.0.0 versions of gensim (in Python 2 or 3), you can use:

```
model.vocab
```

...in gensim 1.0.0+ you should instead use (in Python 2 or 3)...

```
model.wv.vocab
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gensim 3.00+, we can use:

```
    model.wv.key_to_index
```

For more information:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4